# How to Get the Current URL with Certain Condition with PHP or JavaScript?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and still learning but I have a project that needs some certain actions. What I need is to get a url from the current URL after a certain condition and put it on the page as a hyperlink or button.

For example, the current url is http://mywebsite.com/?=https://yourwebsite.com

The output should be a hyperlink or button linking to **https://yourwebsite.com**. Removing http://mywebsite.com/?=

Hope anyone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Who created that URL? If you're going to pass data in as a query param, you should do it correctly by adding a key to the value. Instead of `?=https://...` you should do `?url=https://....` and then just fetch it with `$_GET['url']` in PHP.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You're method also worked. This one is better as I need it to be executed in php. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Step 1: Get the url

`let url = window.location.search`

eg: test.com/?link="www.google.com"

#### Step 2: Get the link parameter from the url

```
let params = new URLSearchParams(url)
let link = params.get('link')
```

(here link = [www.google.com](http://www.google.com))

#### Step 3: Attach link to Link tag

```
document.getElementById('myLink').href = link
```

```
let url = window.location.search 
let params = new URLSearchParams(url)
let link = params.get('link')
document.getElementById('myLink').href = link
```